# Setting the style property for table rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume I have a page like this

```
<html>    
    <body>
        <table id="t1">
            <tr><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
table th { background:color1;} 
table td { background:color2;}
```

How do I change the background color for all rows except header row with a javascript statement. Is looping through each row and column the only method?

I can get `document.getElementById('t1').rows[1]` and `rows[2]` and change background. But is there another efficient way?

Comment: `th` and `td` already have different colors `color1` and `color2` so aren't they already different?

Comment: @Annjawn They are! I want to hightlight just the tds with a different color(different than color2) on a particular client click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can loop over the elements and change the background

```
var els = document.getElementById("t1").getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
  els[i].style.background = "green"   
}
```

Comment: This is what I was planning to do. Was checking if there was some other efficient method.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

put a class on the rows and put backgrounds in css like you do with the tables

Comment: The number of rows are not known in advance. I would guess it is better to loop through each row than give an id for each row. My question is if I can do this without looping!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
table th {background: color1;}
table tbody {background: color2;}

<table id="t1">
    <tr><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th></tr>
    <tbody id="t2">
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the script:

```
document.getElementById('t2').style.backgroundColor=color3;
```

**EDIT**

It's also possible to add a rule to the particular `styleSheet`.

CSS:

```
table th {background: color1;}
table td {background: color2;}
```

Script:

```
var sSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
if (sSheet.insertRule) {
    sSheet.insertRule('td {background-color: color3}', sSheet.cssRules.length);
} else { // For IE < 9
    sSheet.addRule('td', 'background-color: color3', -1);
}
```

You can also modify an existing rule itself:

```
var tdRule,
    sSheet = document.styleSheets[0];       
if (sSheet.cssRules) {
    tdRule = sSheet.cssRules[1];
} else { // For IE < 9
    tdRule = sSheet.rules[1];
}
tdRule.style.backgroundColor = color3;
```

Comment: tbody style would be overidden by td style

Comment: @Jeff That's why there is not `td` style defined in my code :). Ofcourse you can style `td`s, just not set `background` for those.

Comment: @Jeff I've edited my answer. There are now two more methods available to change `background-color` of the `td`s, without any kind of looping.

Answer (score -1):

I use JQuery.

```
$('td').css('background','#3232');
```

Comment: Even for jquery, the code you've written wont work. Its `$(td).css('background','#3232');`